# Redrawing Elycharts in a one document jQuery Mobile environment

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, svg, graphael

I created a statistics web app which is all stored in one HTML document utilizing jQuery mobile to switch around between the different pages. I create a chart with Elycharts ([elycharts.com](http://elycharts.com)) which retrieves the information from the local database. Everytime, when I switch to the page with the charts, I trigger a function loading the entries from the database and drawing the charts.

I ran into the problem, that the first time I load the page, parts of the graphics are missing. When I run it in the browser, it will appear after refresh.

When I add a new entry, the new points are drawn on top of the last entry. It appears, that the chart is drawn on top of the previous version.

Does anybody know, how I can trigger a real clean redrawing or inject dynamically more entries to the output?

I am running in circles since days. The manual is incomplete and the comments in the code are a mix of english and italian ... I thought about switching to another Library, but the charts I created so far are very nice looking and work on the iPad. Just have to get these bugs out.

Sorry I can not provide the code here.

Answer (score 4):

This is maybe a bit late but I run into the same problem today and found this solution to work fine:

```
$("#mychart").chart('clear');
```

hope this helps.

Comment: You save my friday evening! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

After AJAX success call, add this code:

```
$('#chart').remove(); // this will remove the existing old chart and all its values
$("#chartdiv").append('<div id="chart" style="width: auto;height: 450px" \/>');
generatechart(); // this will generate the chart
```

This the HTML:

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: auto;height: 450px"></div>
```